# Replace CSV line using the -replace operator - retain format (PowerShell)

Tags: powershell

I am trying to replace a line in a CSV and retain the array structure, see CSV and code example:

CSV example:

```
Computer,Domain
DC001,contoso.local
DB001,contoso.local
AB001,contoso.local
```

Code:

```
[array]$csv= Import-Csv c:\docs\MyCsv.csv
$newCSv = $csv | ForEach { $_.Domain -replace "contoso", "MyDomainName" }

Output of $newCsv:

MyDomainName.local
MyDomainName.local
MyDomainName.local

Desired output $newCsv:

 Computer Domain       
-------- ------       
DC001    MyDomainName.local
DB001    MyDomainName.local
AB001    MyDomainName.local
```

I have tried piping to`| Select Computer, Domain` but this does not work. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: the output you show is the DISPLAY of the variable content. if you want it converted to a CSV format you need to use `Export-CSV`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not modifying your csv at all, check the output of your command before assigning it to a variable.

```
$csv = @'
Computer,Domain
DC001,contoso.local
DB001,contoso.local
AB001,contoso.local
'@ | ConvertFrom-Csv

$csv | foreach {$_.domain -replace 'contoso','MyDomainName'}

MyDomainName.local
MyDomainName.local
MyDomainName.local
```

You are assigning that output to variable `$newcsv` which has no bearing on the contents of `$csv`. If you want to replace text in one of your properties, you need to do just that.

```
$csv | foreach {$_.domain = $_.domain -replace 'contoso','MyDomainName'} # No output
```

Having assigned the replaced text from property `.domain` back into `.domain` now take a look at the contents of `$csv`

```
$csv

Computer Domain            
-------- ------            
DC001    MyDomainName.local
DB001    MyDomainName.local
AB001    MyDomainName.local
```

Now you can export it

```
$csv | Export-Csv $somefile -NoType
```

Answer (score 2):

To output the new CSV, you need to specify its properties. To change the values in just one column, you can use `Select-Object` with a calculated property:

```
$newCsv = Import-Csv -Path 'D:\Test\MyCsv.csv' | 
          Select-Object Computer, 
                        @{Name = 'Domain';Expression = {$_.Domain -replace "contoso", "MyDomainName" }}

#output on screen
$newCsv

# write to new csv file
$newCsv | Export-Csv -Path 'D:\Test\MyNewCsv.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

Output

```
Computer Domain            
-------- ------            
DC001    MyDomainName.local
DB001    MyDomainName.local
AB001    MyDomainName.local
```